# How can I automate the creation of a firebase firestore database for a given project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

For CI/CD purpose, I'd like to generate my firebase infrastructure as code (so using the web console is not an option).
I'm already able to create the firebase project with the Firebase CLI:

```
firebase projects:create --display-name "MyApp DEV" --token ${FIREBASE_TOKEN} myapp-dev
```

I've check the firebase reference manual, but I can't find any command line tool, API or Admin SDK in any language to create the firestore database.
I know it's possible to create a real time database with `firebase database:instances:create <instanceName>`but, again, i'm not interested by this database, i want to create a firestore database.

I've quickly check the `gcloud` CLI but i haven't found any possibility ere either.

Did I miss anything ? Do you have any solution / workaround.

Comment: If the Firebase CLI doesn't do what you want, please file a feature request with Firebase support so they can gauge interest in this.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for your comment. Do you confirm this feature do not exists ? In that case, since it's a very obvious requirement, i gess there is good reason and I'd like know it. Fore sure someone here will have the (unofficial) explaination.

Comment: I don't know if Stack Overflow is the place to go to get answers to "why" a product is the way it is.  If you want to address Firebase staff directly with open-ended questions, I suggest posting to firebase-talk: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: Basicaly, my question is not "Why" but "How" @DougStevenson. Anyway, Thanks for sharing the forum link : I found a post of a firebase developper on june 2019 saying programatic firestore creation was impossible but could be implemented. I'm asking for any update on this topic.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means? *firebase infrastructure as code*? Firebase Real Time Database and Firestore do not have a pre-defined infrastructure. Nodes (collections/documents) are created as they are written so there's generally no need to pre-create a structure like there is in an SQL database.

Comment: Hi @Jay . Please check infrastructure as code definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code. The purpose is to script your assets creation. Here, i want a programatic way to create a project, a server account, a firestore on europe datacenter with a default security rules, etc. This is not related to the inner structure of the database.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, you can use alpha version of [gcloud for firestore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases/create)
to create a firestore database. Example `gcloud alpha firestore databases create --region=europe-west --project <PROJECT_ID>`. But before that you must first create / have created a Google App Engine app in the corresponding region, in out example `europe-west`. 
So a complete working example should be `gcloud app create --region=europe-west --project <PROJECT_ID> && gcloud alpha firestore databases create --region=europe-west --project <PROJECT_ID>`

Comment: I will try that soon and i'll let you know. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [MBA_Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62435808/10567890) response i have create pipeline to deploy firebase stack from GITLAB CI.

First you need to create empty project to manage entities and api deployment on GCLOUD,add this API to this project :

- https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
- https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appengine.googleapis.com/

Then you need to create service account for the "manager project" with empty rules, copy the email address (something like service-account@manager-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com ).

Go back to organization level and add this email into IAM policy > Add user (paste service account email you have created). Set project.creator role. Go back to project > service account and generate new private key at Json format and download it.

.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
# This variables need to be setup in gitlab project CI/CD variables
variables:
   GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY: Content of service-account.json
   PROJECT_ID : Name of new project
   GCLOUD_ORGANIZATION_ID : Main organization to attach new project
   FIREBASE_TOKEN : Result of command : firebase login:ci

image: google/cloud-sdk:297.0.1-alpine

deploy-firestore-project:
   stage: deploy

   before_script:
      - apk add --update nodejs npm
      - npm install -g firebase-tools
      - gcloud components install alpha
      - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
      - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
   script:
      - gcloud projects create $PROJECT_ID --organization $GCLOUD_ORGANIZATION_ID
      - firebase projects:addfirebase $PROJECT_ID --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
      - gcloud app create --region=europe-west --project $PROJECT_ID
      - gcloud alpha firestore databases create --region=europe-west --project $PROJECT_ID --quiet
```

Note :

1. If you don't run : firebase projects:addfirebase i don't see my new project in firebase dashboard and i'm not enable to use it.
2. You can use the same process to create a service-account for all firestore project of organization (depends of your security requirements).

Comment: Last step will be to set default region for the project ... Firebase continue to show default region is not defined .. It's possible via [firebase management api ](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.defaultLocation/finalize#try-it) and it's work, but i don't know how to use that in my CI for the moment.. Work in progress